# Add dynamic geographic maps

Tags: graphics, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [geographic maps with TikZ/pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36059/geographic-maps-with-tikz-pgfplots)

I would like to include maps in a document and I'm thinking that it would be great to have them dynamically generated. I'm wondering if a package already exists. Ideally, I would write something like:

```
\begin{map}[width=100px,
            height=80px,
            title="My new map"]
   \poi[name="My house"]{-71}{42}
\end{map}
```

You would then have `\listofmaps`, `\listofpois` and `\mapofpois` commands for indexes.

Is there already such a package?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean something like [this](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-geo)?

Comment: @Azoun: maps like this, but limited to a given zone (my example is not great in this regard I confess), and including optional POI markers.

Comment: The parameters for `\poi` are supposed to be latitude and longitude? If there where to be a package, or someone crazy enough (not me) decides to write one, wouldn't it be preferable to have vector output, i.e. width=2cm instead of pixels? I'm thinking along the lines of including a vector map (e.g. https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/ref_maps/pdf/political_world.pdf ) and then clipping the output with TikZ, which would also allow adding POIs easily.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36059/geographic-maps-with-tikz-pgfplots