# Can TiKZ create maps?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible/feasible to draw a complex irregular shape (e.g., a map of a land mass) in `tikz`? Specifically:

- I want to create a map of the island in [*Lord of the Flies*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399501487) (for instructional purposes, if it matters)
- I need not only the outline but certain geographical features (mountain, forest, population concentrations, &c.)

I did find [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36059/geographic-maps-with-tikz-pgfplots), but it really deals with maps of actually existing places, and the use of actual lat/lon data to build the map; I would be working solely from the description provided in the novel.

I have no MWE because I don't even really know how to get started with this question.

Comment: yes it can create maps. But you need to have some sort of coordinates or you have to draw with inkscape and convert it to a TikZ path