# Generate a world map in LaTeX

Tags: getmap

I need to generate a world map with colored countries to be included in LaTeX. I tried different things like `\getmap` but nothing worked so far. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: do you mean that you have a package that documents a `\getmap` command that didn't work or do you mean you just hoped a command such as `\getmap` might somehow work by magic? Your question really is not very clear.

Comment: the normal way would be to get an image of a map and use `\includegraphics{map-picture}` using the `graphicx` package.

Comment: There is a package called `getmap`, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean. Generally, you are not going to get much luck just trying to 'guess' commands  (e.g., `\getanswer`)....

Comment: Perhaps `pst-geo` is a tool that might be helpful

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183087/draw-colored-world-us-map-in-latex/183138#183138

Comment: Do you mean a projected map based on a particular coordinate system, with LaTeX labels, i.e. a GIS type map?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I certainly did not try to guess a command but found that package along with the doc. on CTAN.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using in the form of a small document we can try to compile to see what's going on? What happens? Do you get an error? What is it? Or does the output look wrong? What's not as you expected?

Comment: What makes you think that any of the services offered provides a world map?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36059/8141

Answer (score 23):

Run with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-geo}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\psset{path=Links/texmf-local-generic/pst-geo/data/}%% change to your system

\begin{center}      
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-3.5)(7,3.5)
  \psframe*[linecolor=black!30](-7,-3.5)(7,3.5)
  \WorldMap[type=4,unit=0.7]% other types are possible
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7)
  \psframe*[linecolor=black!30](-7,-7)(7,7)
  \WorldMapThreeD[PHI=30,THETA=0]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting and nice to have such a package!

Comment: This is a very good map to have. however when I compile the code I get dark gray colored rectangles with nothing in two files, myfile.pdf and myfile-pics.pdf. In the log file, the error I see is "Vtex not found" I have replaced the path to "\psset{path=/usr/share -doc/texlive-doc/generic/pst-geo/data}". What could be the problem?

Comment: The path looks wrong to me. Run `kpsewhich pst-geo` in a terminal and you'll get the correct path where the data files are saved.

Answer (score 17):

`getmap` works, sort of, if you set the `zoom` level to 1 you get the most of the world. The projection is bad though.

Note that you must compile with `shell-escape` enabled, i.e. `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`, not `pdflatex file.tex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{getmap,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\getmap[file=theworld,mode=gm,type=terrain,xsize=500,ysize=500,%
scale=2,zoom=1]{60,5}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{theworld}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need a map, eg [this one from wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/PietroCoppo.jpg) then include into latex as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PietroCoppo}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use this beautiful map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hereford-Karte.jpg ;-).

Comment: I don't like to live in that map. scary.